# Code First mapping

Tags: mapping, ef-code-first

I'm trying to map a Department to an Employee.

This is the Department Class:

```
Class Department
    Property DepartID As Integer = 0
    Property DepartName As String
End Class
```

If I define the Employee Class as follows:

```
Class Employee
    Property EmployeeID As Integer
    Property DepartID As Integer

    ' Navigational Property
    Overridable Property Depart As Department
End Class
```

As you can see, the structure is very simple. Basically the Employee Table stores a Department ID, and I would like to automatically populate the Department Property.

I am easily able to map the Foreign Key using Fluent API if I have the Foreign ID field defined in Employee:

```
.HasRequired(Function(e) e.Depart).WithMany.HasForeignKey(Function(e) e.DepartID).WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
```

However, I would like to acheive the same without defining an ID property (DepartID) in the Employee Table. It's just going to be a bit cleaner, as I don't have to have multiple ID fields. Is it possible?

Comment: If there's no DepartID in Employee *table* how are you going to know to what Department the Employee belongs?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean DepartID in Employee class (not table, see my comment). If so, you can use [ForeignKeyNavigationPropertyConfiguration.Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.foreignkeynavigationpropertyconfiguration.map%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) method to map it without the FK in model.

Comment: Yes, correct, I meant in Employee class, not Table. I'll try the ForeignKeyNavigationPropertyConfiguration.Map method as you mentioned. Haven't had the chance to do so yet.